# Importing from a PostGIS database into Carto using Carto's Import API

Tags: postgis, carto, import

I am not new to Carto, but I'm new to the command line. I am able to import local files using this sample code Carto has in their documentation:

```
curl -v -F file=@/home/documentation/Documents/prism_tour.csv
"https://documentation.carto.com/api/v1/imports/?api_key=3102343c42da0f1ffe6014594acea8b1c4e7fd64"
```

I want to connect to and import from an existing PostGIS DB I have. Carto's documentation shows the following code:

```
{
  "connector": {
    "provider": "postgres",
    "connection": {
      "server":"pgserver.com",
      "database":"pgdatabase",
      "username":"pgusername",
      "password":"pgpassword"
    },
    "schema": "public",
    "table": "pgtable"
  }
}
```

I have all the parameters needed. But 1. I don't know how to force lines without them executing. (everything is one line) For this reason, seems that the terminal is only running the first line and the error I get is " 'connector' is not recognized as an internal command.

Does this have anything to do with setting up environment variables?

And how do I type this on the command line so that it looks like a block of code like in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This direct Postgres-level connection is Enterprise plan special feature, it is not generally available to anyone.

There are other options, have you considered to use one of these:

a) export data from your PostGIS to CSV (or geopackage, geojson or shapefile), and then use Import API

b) use `ogr2ogr` conversion, this is preferable for smaller datasets. Something like:

```
ogr2ogr --config CARTO_API_KEY abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw -f Carto "Carto:myaccount" PG:"dbname='databasename' host='addr' port='5432' user='x' password='y'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do have access to an enterprise account. Is this something for which I need to contact Carto to have it specifically "turned on"?

Comment: Yes, check with your enterprise support contact. I think even with this connection you wil not get ”live” data, but regular sync with given interval, for performance reasons. So functionally other options may be similar.

Comment: @JaakL for enterprise account, the entire postgres database with the tables can be synced at one time?

Comment: AFAIK with the conector you need some DDL for each table, but better check with offial support directly.

Answer (score 2):

I figured I should share what worked for me in the end. If anyone has a better solution, feel free to share it. But so far this works (seemingly) flawlessly.

I installed [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads), wrote the entire command as above in a text editor and pasted it at once into git bash. Note of advice, it's a lot more useful in the long run to modify the command to include an interval for the data to sync with the postgres DB.

If anyone has trouble with this method and hasn't found any other solution, feel free to reach out to me. I'm not an expert but I'm willing to try new alternatives and learn more.

Comment: can you post your entire command? I am in the same exact situation as you

Comment: @ziggy     `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "connector": {"provider": "postgres","connection": {"server": "MYSERVERNAME","database": "MYDBNAME", "username": "MYDB_USERNAME", "password": "MYDB_PASSWORD"}, "table" : "MYTABLE"}, "interval": 3600}' "https://CARTO_USERNAME.carto.com/api/v1/imports/?api_key=MYAPIKEY"`

Comment: One useful tool you might want to check out is the Postman Google chrome extension-- it's a good GUI to use with APIs and it helped me a lot when I started pushing data to Carto through CURL.

Comment: okay I actually got mine to run but my table is empty... do any column names have to be named something specific?

Comment: So the table imports, but only the headers show up with no rows?

Comment: it says the table imports but not even the columns are there, here is my command which says successful when ran from git

Comment: `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "connector": { "provider": "postgres", "connection": { "server":"noury", "database":"macomb", "username":"postgres", "password":"blah" }, "table": "carto_test" } }' "abid.carto.com/api/v1/synchronizations/?api_key="`

Comment: Hmmm I'm not entirely sure, but maybe re-write your URL to read `abid.carto.com/api/v1/imports/?api_key=`

Comment: Currently, yours says synchronizations rather than imports and that perhaps contributes to the issue?

Comment: didn't work :(.

Comment: Have you checked that this functionality is enabled? If I remember correctly, I had to reach out to my Carto contact to enable this feature on my account before I was able to do it successfully